# Finding a min weight matching of a specific size

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, operations-research, matching-theory

For a complete graph $G=(V,E)$, i want to find a minimim weighted matching of a size $n$ where $n \leq \lvert V \rvert$ is there any known algorithms for such a problem other than IP formulations?

Comment: Is the graph bipartite?

Comment: It seems like the blossom algorithm can be adapted to do this; we can make sure to pick the minimum-weight augmenting path at each step, and if we do, then after $k$ steps we will have the minimum-weight $k$-edge matching.

Comment: @user7530 No the graph is complete such that every vertex is connected by an edge.

Comment: @MishaLavrov but would that ensure an optimal solution?

Comment: @MagnusM Yes, it would; this is essentially the reason why the blossom algorithm can find a max-weight (or min-weight) perfect matching to begin with. I'm personally kind of scared of the blossom algorithm and would not be able to explain the details of how it finds an *optimal* augmenting path, but I can prove that being able to do that is enough.

Comment: @MishaLavrov I am familiar with the blossom algorithm, but mostly for finding the maximum matchins in a non-weighted graph. I will look more into it, thanks.